# using jQuery .get within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery .get call that hits a URL which returns true or false based on whether the user is signed in or not.  This allows me to redirect the user to a login form if they aren't authenticated rather than the entire page being displayed in a small div (which holds content a signed in user should be able to see)

I think there is a problem with my .get syntax:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

          function logInCheck() {

              $.get({{ path('signed_in_check') }}, function(data) {

                  var loggedIn = data;
                  alert(loggedIn);

              });

          }
      logInCheck();
});
```

This doesn't work, and even if I replace alert(loggedIn) with alert("hello"), the alert doesn't get called.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: your script is have some visible syntax issues, you have two following commas (", ,") and also function logInCheck must be defined before document.ready. try to fix them and retry

Comment: Took out the 1 of the 2 commas, and tried moving the code above document.ready, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad typos in your code.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
      function logInCheck() {
          $.get(path('signed_in_check'), function(data) {
              var loggedIn = data;
              alert(loggedIn);
          });
      }
      logInCheck();
});
```

It should work for now.

Comment: Where are the typos?  And, path('signed_in_check') won't do anything.  {{ path('signed_in_check') }} is a twig function, it is replaced with a URL before execution.

Comment: Exactly what does `{{ path('signed_in_check') }}` produce?

Comment: It produces http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/signed_in_check which displayed either true or false when I hit it from the browser.

Comment: I guess it's good enough to download Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) and do `Inspect element` > `Console` tab, then execute the function and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do this with firebug. Pointed me straight to the answer "Invalid regular expression".  I didn't put quotes around the {{ }} path placeholder.  I guess that means it's time for some sleep.

Comment: Firebug makes web development easier. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$(document).ready(function() {

```
          $.get(path('signed_in_check'), function(data) {

              var loggedIn = data;
              alert(loggedIn);

          });

      });
```